# Can I export to multiple tabs in the same Excel file?

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to export data from AG-grid to multiple tabs in the same Excel file.  I can export to one tab but how do i export to multiple tabs in the same file using ag-grid version 20?

I can export to a single tab but I cannot find anything in the documentation for multiple tabs in the same file.

Comment: by tabs you mean excel sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting to multiple excel sheets is not supported in the current version of ag-Grid and as far as I can tell from the release pipeline this won't be the case in the near future.

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/

If you really need to generate multiple sheets in excel, then one possibility is to create it manually, for instance with exceljs:

https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs